# How to draw pattern on a sphere

Tags: maya

Can someone help me model the image below? 
I tried different ways and had no luck
I am still a very beginner in MAYA and appreciate any help you guys can give me
I tried making the pattern by moving the vertices and smooth them but that didnt work.
[image]

Comment: You should check some basic Maya tutorials instead... As it is your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

A quick top level comment - the pattern you see here *most **likely*** isn't based in  the geometry directly - that is, the verts were probably unchanged from a basic sphere primitive.

It **looks** to me like a simple procedural texture applied to that sphere.

**Note:** I could well be wrong, but if I were producing that image myself, unless there were some over-riding reason for the pattern to dictate polyflow, I'd just use a procedural texture to get there.